# How to convert two numbers into time(h:m:s) with twig

Tags: php, twig, converters

So I have for example
{{ example['time'] }}
Which returns 0-240

How I can make it to be 00:00 - 04:00 for example

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the output has `-` between the numbers it can't be modified with the filter `|date`. However when I split them and apply the filter then, e.g. `|date("H:i:s")`, it worked like a charm

Comment: If you resolved your own problem, you should mark your own answer as accepted for better visibility ;-)

Comment: Sure thing  :) It says I can do it in two days, so I'll wait a bit.Thanks ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Twig filters to format your date:

```
{{ example['time']|date("m/d/Y") }}
```

Have a look at the [official documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date.html), there are many examples which might be usefull for you.

If those filter doesn't suit your needs you can also write your own filter by creating a new [Twig Extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html)

Comment: Not sure if this will display `00:00 - 04:00` from `0-240`.